# How do I dynamically append something to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I have a form like so:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['artist'])) {
      // do something
    } ?>
<form name="admin_on_artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>" action="" method="POST">
    <p class="artist-negative">
        <label for="artist"><input type="checkbox" name="artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>" id="artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>"> Check this?</label>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

On the page in question, this form is shown many times in a foreach loop. However, when I submit any given form, it updates all of the forms, which is not what I want.

How can I append the `$artist->ID` to `$_POST['artist']` so that I get something like:

`$_POST['artist_1']` to match the checkbox attributes?

Comment: how about a hidden form input with the id?

Answer (score 0):

You could pair your `foreach` that generates the frontend form markup with a `foreach` that processes the form submission. Something like:

```
<?php
$regex = '/^artist_([0-9]+)$/'
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    if (preg_match($regex,$key,$matches)) {
        $artistId = (int)$matches[1];
        // do something with $_POST[$key] according to $artistId
    }
}
```

This works for a single field submission or a multiple field submission.

Alternatively, you could do something on the frontend in `JS` (as @smith suggests in the comments) to ensure the form submission always has the same, well-known keys, populating a hidden form with the current submission. With this approach you would have to add another field to the form that contains the ID.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was much simpler than I was able to grasp at first, but basically I just had to do this, the key difference between this and my original question being the first two lines:

```
<?php $artist_form_id = 'artist_'.$artist->ID;
if (isset($_POST[$artist_form_id])) {
  // do something
} ?>
<form name="admin_on_artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>" action="" method="POST">
    <p class="artist-negative">
        <label for="artist"><input type="checkbox" name="artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>" id="artist_<?php echo $artist->ID; ?>"> Check this?</label>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```